# C# Inconsistent accessibility : parameter type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error I can't find how to fix here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MITM_Omar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          ClientListener Client = new ClientListener();
            Client.ClientConnected += clientconnect;
        }
        public void clientconnect(ClientListener client)
        {
            ServeurListener Serveur = new ServeurListener("213.248.126.39", 5555);
            client.associated = Serveur;
            Serveur.associated = client;
            client.onReception += forwadtoserver;
            Serveur.onReception += forwadtoclient;
            Serveur.connect(); 
        }
        public void forwadtoclient(ServeurListener sender, byte[] buffer)
        {
            sender.associated.send(buffer);
        }
        public void forwadtoserver(ClientListener sender, byte[] buffer)
        {
            sender.associated.send(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error Inconsistent accessibility : parameter type'MITM_OMAR.ClientListener' is less accessible than method 'MITM_OMAR.Form1.clientconnect(MITM_OMAR.ClientListener)

Here's the Client Listener class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
namespace MITM_Omar
{
    class ClientListener
    {
        public Socket _Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        public Thread _ConnectionThread;
        public Thread _ReceptionThread;


        public delegate void onClientActionEventHandler(ClientListener client);
        public event onClientActionEventHandler ClientConnected;


        public delegate void onTravellingDataEventHandler(ClientListener sender, byte[] buffer);
        public event onTravellingDataEventHandler onReception;
        public ServeurListener associated;
       public ClientListener()
        {
            _ConnectionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(accept));
            _Socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5555);
            _ConnectionThread.Start();
            _ReceptionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Reception));
            _ReceptionThread.Start();
        }
        public void accept()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Socket socket = _Socket.Accept();
                if (ClientConnected != null)
                {
                    ClientConnected(this);
                }
            }

        }
        public void send(byte[] data)
        {
            _Socket.Send(data);


        }
        public void Reception()
        {
            // On reçoit les données tant qu'on est connecté.
            while (_Socket.Connected)
            {
                // On crée notre buffer dynamique.
                byte[] _buffer = new byte[_Socket.Available];

                // Si le buffer n'est pas vide, on le parse.
                if (_buffer.Length != 0)
                {
                    _Socket.Receive(_buffer); // Récéption des données.
                    if (onReception != null) onReception(this, _buffer); // un event qui dit qui a reçu des données et le tableau de bytes reçu

                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Make the `ClientListener` class public.  It is currently private.

Comment: This question has many duplicates. Please search to see if your problem is already reported, and solved, by someone else.

Comment: Thanks guys I didn't notice it ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your class public.

```
public class ClientListener
...
```

The default access for a class if you do not specify one explicitly is internal.  Internal is less accessible than public, therefore you're getting an error.

Comment: but internal works for the entire assembly!! But why does it creates such error message when two classes are in same assembly?

Comment: @VijayVj - its because, access specifier of other class - Form1 is public. public means it can be accessible outside of assembly so if you would use internal class in Form 1, its of no use as internal can't be accessed outside so less accessible as it is restricting power of public. If you are sure your Form 1 class is not going to be used outside then make it internal and then you can use other internal class inside it.